# Question regarding date of entry for form I-765

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I am a US Citizen. My spouse who is a Vietnamese citizen in the US on an F-1 visa and I traveled to Canada for a day trip. 
She got an entry stamp into Canada but no stamp re-entering USA. The trip does not show in her I-94 online page.

Should we figure out the date and place of entry for the I-765 even though she has no stamp or I-94 info for it?

If we shouldn't, then what should we use for this.

Answer (score 2):

You will have re-entered the US under *automatic revalidation*, a program where nonimmigrant visitors to the US can visit Canada, Mexico and various Caribbean countries for up to 30 days and then return to the US under their previous admission, rather than a new admission.

Your date and place of entry will be your original entry, not your entry from your short visit to Canada.